# Move items between checklists on the same card in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I have two checklists on a particular card. I am able to reorder the items within a checklist. Is it possible to move an item from one checklist into another checklist, within the same card?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Simply drag the item from one checklist to the other.

Here's a screenshot

[image]